# packaging and referencing .net private dll assemblies in Matlab

Tags: .net, matlab

EDIT (24 June 2013):

I think I may have partly found the root cause of the problem.

Instead of just running the .exe on the test machine, I run and compile the Matlab source codes. When Matlab tried to add the 3rd party assembly, an error popped i.e. "Unable to load one or more of the requested type etc2". Upon further investigation, I found out that the 3rd party dll depends on another dll i.e. NationalInstruments.Common, version=8.1.0.415, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4544464cdeaab541. I checked the GAC on the test machine and it has NationalInstruments.Common version 8.9.35.302 instead. The funny thing is my development machine also has this same version of NI .Common dll but I'm perplexed why the .exe works on my machine but not on the test machine.

I googled this up and someone suggested doing assembly binding redirect. But the example was for development in Visual Studio using C#. I was wondering is there a way to do the same thing in Matlab directly?

END EDIT

I am developing a simple Matlab application/GUI that, at a push of a button, takes data from an external hardware and plot them. The vendor provides an API to access this hardware in a form of .net dll assemblies. So, in Matlab, I added the assembly using NET.addAssembly. However, I have to give its full path since it is a private assembly. When I compile the code into .exe, it runs fine on my machine. However, when I took it over to another machine, it does not run. FYI, Matlab's MCR with the right version is installed in the other machine so the problem is not due to missing MCR.

I think the problem is because when I reference the dll in the NET.addAssembly, I used the full path to locate the dll on my machine. So, on the other machine, it could not find it. So i tried putting the dll in a same folder on the other machine but it failed to run. I also tried packaging the dll when compiling the .exe but that did not work as well.

Can someone advise what should I do next? Thanks!

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @Nathan Henkel - There's no error message. It just that the executable does not run on machines other than the development machine. I looked in the Processes tab of Task Manager when clicking the executable icon. The executable did run for a brief period and then stopped. But the GUI did not come up at all.

Comment: Do both machines have the same version of the .NET framework?

Comment: Yes, both machines have .NET 4.0 Framework.

Comment: What is the path to the DLL on the original machine? If it's in a standard folder like Program Files, then there are methods of retrieving the folder path automatically. However, a more robust solution is to check if the file exists where you think it is and if not, then have the user enter the path to their installation (then store this in a settings file).

Comment: What version of Matlab, by the way?